# NotificationCompat.Builder mActions field is now restricted, so how do I update action?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have been using `NotificationCompat.Builder` to create my media control notification. When the playback state changes, I update the notification accordingly. The snippet below should give an idea of what I have been doing.

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder;

mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
    // Prebuild the notification
    mNotificationBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_statusbar)
            .setContentIntent(mSessionActivityIntent)
            .setDeleteIntent(closePendingIntent)
            .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.round_skip_previous_white_36, "Previous", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS)))
            .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.round_play_arrow_white_36, "Play", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)))
            .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.round_skip_next_white_36, "Next", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT)))
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_TRANSPORT)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setStyle(new MediaStyle().setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2)
                        .setMediaSession(mMediaSessionToken));
```

When the playback state changes between playing and paused, I update the notification to change the play/pause button.

```
...
mNotificationBuilder.mActions.set(1, new NotificationCompat.Action(playIcon, "Play", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, action)));
...
```

This was working without any problem before, and it still does. The problem is that the `mActions` field is now restricted. I found this in the `NotificationCompat.java` sources.

```
/** @hide */
    @RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP)
    public ArrayList<Action> mActions = new ArrayList<>();
```

It's really weird that this field would be hidden now without providing any method to update it. I'm afraid that this field would become completely inaccessible in the future. Any ideas?

Comment: Recreate the `Builder` with your updated action values. I would say that it's not really typical to keep and modify a instance of a previously used `Builder` object anyway.

Comment: @MikeM. That should work. I've keeping the instance around because I read somewhere in the Android docs that we should "cache" the builder for efficiency. I don't exactly remember which builder it was about though.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Though it does not causes compilation error but gives a lint warning. One way is to remove and add the action again for play pause scenario.